# Does ExpressJS have any security features built-in?

Tags: node.js, express

I've searched through the documentation and couldn't find any particulars on what kind of security ExpressJS provides. I normally work with Node's HTTP module, so I guess that's what I'm comparing with

Comment: which of the `http` module's features do you want to compare express with?

Comment: `createServer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is the ExpressJS security page: http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html

But as you can see on the page, ExpressJS mostly seems to delegate anything but the most basic security to other middlewares.  A good starting point, as the page suggests, is Helmet (https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet), which provides some sensible defaults

You should also consider implementing CSRF protection with the csurf middleware and, of course, enabling HTTPS as a formality.